# PHP: Simple read data from part of a string?

Tags: php, string

From this string

```
{"ticker":{"high":1.747,"low":1.6,"vol":13755,"buy":1.608,"sell":1.68,"last":1.61}}
```

I need to get the "last" data (currently 1.61) I know there's an easy answer, but I'm not sure exactly what it is.

Comment: that's a json string. just use json_decode()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$values = json_decode($string, true);
echo $values['ticker']['last'];
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json, http://php.net/json_decode.

Comment: That's an easy answer, thanks. Will accept as soon as system allows.